# How to use subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've performance problems with this query:

```
SELECT * 
          FROM post 
          JOIN post_plus 
          ON post_plus.news_id = post.id 
         WHERE category in(130,3) 
           AND approve=1 
           AND allow_main=1 
      ORDER BY kp_votes DESC, 
               kp_rating DESC LIMIT 30;
```

[Optimizing join query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21779741/optimizing-join-query)

What I'd like to try is convert the above query to a "subquery" instead of using JOIN

What I've tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM post
WHERE category in(130,3)
    (SELECT *
     FROM post_plus
     WHERE post_plus.news_id = post.id)
  AND approve=1
  AND allow_main=1
ORDER BY fixed DESC,
         kp_votes DESC,
         kp_rating DESC LIMIT 10;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '(select kp_votes kp_rating from post_plus
>   WHERE post_plus.news_id = ' at line 1

Comment: are all the columns in your where clause coming from post_plus?

Comment: Using a subquery most likely won't improve performance but on the contrary. Do all your columns have proper indexes on them that you join and/or filter by?

Comment: Also, it would help if you'd prefix the columns by tables of rather their aliases so it's visible where they belong

Comment: @markg no, some from post some from pust_plus.

Comment: If you want us to help optimize a query, **you need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com ASAP.

Comment: @fejese Yes I do... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21779741/optimizing-join-query

Comment: Try http://sqlfiddle.com to provide an example

Comment: @Orlo if it's about the same query - why do you create another question for the same thing?

Comment: @poncha I ask `How to use subquery?` not `How to optimize my join query`

Comment: @Orlo I already started to write an answer and then figured it will be a very large one and will quote a lot of what manual has to say.. Maybe it's best if you first read the [**manual**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/subqueries.html) on the subject... It explains in detail several subquery use cases.

Answer (score 1):

Fixing the syntax error would be this:

```
SELECT *
FROM post,
     (SELECT *
     FROM post_plus
     WHERE post_plus.news_id = post.id) tmp
WHERE category in(130,3)
  AND approve=1
  AND allow_main=1
ORDER BY fixed DESC,
         kp_votes DESC,
         kp_rating DESC LIMIT 10;
```

However I strongly believe that this is less optimal than the original join.
It's rather a matter of indexing I guess. Could you show the indexes from the `post` table?

Comment: it's not indexing! when you order calumns from second table it's always `Using temporary; Using filesort` here's a similar case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335177/mysql-performance-inner-join-how-to-avoid-using-temporary-and-filesort

Comment: @Orlo in many cases, when mysql resorts to `filesort` - that is because of bad indexes.

Answer (score 0):

1. user Inner JOIN instead of JOIN to select only the matched rows. (A good Examples for join [What is the difference between Left, Right, Outer and Inner Joins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448023/what-is-the-difference-between-left-right-outer-and-inner-joins/448080#448080)). it bring you maybe performance.
2. use indexes (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-indexes.html) to accelerate your select.

Comment: Isn't `JOIN` the same as `INNER JOIN`?

Answer (score -1):

If optimization is not the problem here and you just want an alternative to `JOIN` then you could probably use [WHERE EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

In your case it could be:

```
SELECT *
FROM post
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT *
 FROM post_plus
 WHERE post_plus.news_id = post.id)
AND category in(130,3)
AND approve=1
AND allow_main=1
ORDER BY fixed DESC,
     kp_votes DESC,
     kp_rating DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: I'm getting `ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'kp_votes' in 'order clause'`

Comment: Check the spelling of your fields in your table definition if it is really `kp_votes`. Or it could be that `kp_votes` belongs to `post_plus` and not `post` table?

Comment: kp_votes and kp_rating belong to `post_plus`. I tried changing to `post_plus.kp_votes` but I get the same `Unknown column 'post_plus.kp_votes' in 'order clause` I guess the subquery doesn't work.

Comment: The `*` from `post` only has fields from `post` table and therefore `ORDER BY` from `post_plus` will have an error unless you use `JOIN` like in your original query then that would work.